# Refreshing Gridview inside SherlockFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to refresh my Gridview images which is inside a SherlockFragment.

I wrote a interface to update the adapter. But all the views are throwing NullPointerException when i try to invoke it using my custom override interface(onCardTypeSelected) method.

I tried my level best. Cant able to find solution. Need some help
Below is my code snippet.

```
 public class PhotosFragment extends SherlockFragment implements CardSelectionInterface {
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.thumb_card1,
            R.drawable.thumb_card2,
            R.drawable.thumb_card3,
            R.drawable.thumb_card4
    };
     View view;
     GridView gridView;  
     String[] cardTypes;
     Context context;
     public static PhotoImageAdapter photoImageAdapter;

     @Override
        public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photos_layout,container,false);
            gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.photogridview);
            context = view.getContext();
            photoImageAdapter = new PhotoImageAdapter(context, mThumbIds);
            gridView.setAdapter(photoImageAdapter); // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity().

            cardTypes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.card_types);

            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    System.out.println("*** Clicked : " + position);
                }
            });
            System.out.println("Returning view");
            return view;
        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("On Activity created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCardTypeSelected(TypedArray typedArrayImages) {
        mThumbIds = new Integer[typedArrayImages.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < typedArrayImages.length(); i++) 
            mThumbIds[i] = typedArrayImages.getResourceId(i, -1);
        this.photoImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        System.out.println("OnAttach");
    }

}
```

Comment: Post logcat or your adapter class..?

Comment: this.photoImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
In the avove line throws NullpointrException . That is the error

Comment: Why are you make it as a static??

Comment: just tried from updating another fragment. When i changed non static also it shows same exception.

Comment: before refreshing list is it coming good??I think after this onCardTypeSelected() is executed some of your mThumbIds data may be null thats why after refreshing your list it giving you NPE..try to change code like this..

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but when i use context value inside onCardTypeSelected() , it also gives null value!!!. Please guide me for that

Comment: is this null  Context context;??

Comment: i m initializing context in OnCreateView. Then y its null in my interface method.